# Confluence: Bill plugins per specific users, not whole users of the organization

Tags: confluence

Do you know please if there is a way to manage the plugins to activate them only for a few users and then be only billed for those users ( and not for the whole company users )?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is *not* possible. Each add-on/app has to be licenced for the same number of users as the Confluence instance.